# Updating state with new Firestore Documents in Snapshot Listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to listen to documents updated in a collection.

I'm having a bit of difficulty adding the new documents to the array. I get the existing docs but when theres new ones added its not updating my state. How do I do this?

### fetchChat.js

```
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";

export const fetchChat = async (uid) => {
  const collectionRef = firestore()
    .collection(`users/${uid}/messages`)
    .orderBy("sent_at", "asc")
    .limit(20);
  const messages = [];
  try {
    const unsubscribe = collectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      messages.length = 0;
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        messages.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
      return messages;
    });
    return { messages, unsubscribe };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error listening to collection:", error);
  }
};
```

### chat.jsx

```
  const [existingMessages, setExistingMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getChat();
  }, []);

  const getChat = async () => {
    const { messages, unsubscribe } = await fetchChat(user.uid);
    setExistingMessages(messages);
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchChat` returns a value, and can only do that once for each time you call it.

So instead of returning the messages from `fetchChat`, you should let `fetchChat` update the state. Merging the two code blocks into one, it becomes:

```
const [existingMessages, setExistingMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  const unsubscribe = collectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const messages = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
    });
    setExistingMessages(messages);
    setLoading(false);
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```